# unable to make the item as selected in mfc listctrl

Tags: mfc

Items are being added to the CListCtrl. If a particular item is present in the list then that item needs to be selected.
I have tried the following code,but the item is not being selected.

```
BOOL CsampleeeDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
     m_List.InsertColumn(0, _T("Full Name"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);
     m_List.InsertColumn(1, _T("Profession"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);
     m_List.InsertColumn(2, _T("Fav Sport"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);

     int nIndex = m_List.InsertItem(0, _T("Sandra C. Anschwitz"));
     m_List.SetItemText(nIndex, 1, _T("Singer"));
     m_List.SetItemText(nIndex, 2, _T("Handball"));

     nIndex = m_List.InsertItem(1, _T("Roger A. Miller"));
     m_List.SetItemText(nIndex, 1, _T("Footballer"));
     m_List.SetItemText(nIndex, 2, _T("Tennis"));

    int nCol = 0;  
    CString m_SearchThisItemText = _T("Sandra C. Anschwitz");
    int var=-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < m_List.GetItemCount(); i++)
    {
        CString szText = m_List.GetItemText(i, nCol);
        if (szText == m_SearchThisItemText)
        {    
        var=i;
        }
    }
    m_List.SetFocus();
    m_List.SetItemState (var, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED);
    m_List.GetSelectionMark();

        return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
    }
```

Can you please let me know what is missing here?any hints?.
Thanks for the help

Comment: if var isn't -1 it should show a selected item. Did you use LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS? If not the item is only shown as selected if it has the focus.

Comment: yes var is not -1 here.using LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS did not select the item

Comment: try this `m_List.SetItemState (var, LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED, LVIS_SELECTED | LVIS_FOCUSED);`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is hinted at by the boilerplate comment to the return statement. Any selection you make to the CListCtrl will be removed if the focus is set to some other control. And that is exactly what will happen if you return `TRUE`. Windows will set the focus to the default control on the dialog, probably the OK button.

So you fix it by `return FALSE;` from OnInitDialog, without setting the focus to anything else before returning.

[image]